# Getting value of compared array[2] in case array[1].value = array[2].key

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I have a sample json `Array1`:

```
[
  {
    "name": "Primary Category",
    "value": [
      {
        "value": "Fracture",
        "Diagnosis_Code": ["DIAG003"],
        "name": "Primary Category",
        "FK_Diagnosis_Content_ID": 3,
        "FK_Diagnosis_Category_ID": 1
      },
      {
        "value": "Osteoarthritis",
        "Diagnosis_Code": ["DIAG001"],
        "name": "Primary Category",
        "FK_Diagnosis_Content_ID": 1,
        "FK_Diagnosis_Category_ID": 1
      },
      {
        "value": "Osteonecrosis",
        "Diagnosis_Code": ["DIAG002", "DIAG004"],
        "name": "Primary Category",
        "FK_Diagnosis_Content_ID": 2,
        "FK_Diagnosis_Category_ID": 1
      },
    ]
  },
  {
    "name": "Anatomy",
    "value": [
      {
        "value": "Hip",
        "Diagnosis_Code": ["DIAG001"],
        "name": "Anatomy",
        "FK_Diagnosis_Content_ID": 4,
        "FK_Diagnosis_Category_ID": 2
      },
      {
        "value": "Pelvis",
        "Diagnosis_Code": ["DIAG002", "DIAG003", "DIAG004"],
        "name": "Anatomy",
        "FK_Diagnosis_Content_ID": 6,
        "FK_Diagnosis_Category_ID": 2
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

and I have a 2nd sample json `Array2`:

```
[ 'Primary Category': 'Fracture', 'Anatomy': 'Pelvis' ]
```

As you see on `Array2` there's some value `Fracture and Pelvis` and i want to get `Array1.FK_Diagnosis_Content_ID` depending on `Array2 value`

so depending on `Array2` I'll have a result : [2, 6] Because `Fracture` in `Array1` has `FK_Diagnosis_Content_ID` = 2 and `Pelvis` in `Array1` has `FK_Diagnosis_Content_ID` = 6

I have spending a lot of time to do that, but I'm not to good to handling an array,

Is there a way how to get the result?

Comment: `Array2` is an invalid object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've corrected `Array2` to be a valid array.

You can use [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) on the first array and in each iteration, check if item's value is included in `Array2`:

```js
const Array1 = [{"name":"Primary Category","value":[{"value":"Fracture","Diagnosis_Code":["DIAG003"],"name":"Primary Category","FK_Diagnosis_Content_ID":3,"FK_Diagnosis_Category_ID":1},{"value":"Osteoarthritis","Diagnosis_Code":["DIAG001"],"name":"Primary Category","FK_Diagnosis_Content_ID":1,"FK_Diagnosis_Category_ID":1},{"value":"Osteonecrosis","Diagnosis_Code":["DIAG002","DIAG004"],"name":"Primary Category","FK_Diagnosis_Content_ID":2,"FK_Diagnosis_Category_ID":1}]},{"name":"Anatomy","value":[{"value":"Hip","Diagnosis_Code":["DIAG001"],"name":"Anatomy","FK_Diagnosis_Content_ID":4,"FK_Diagnosis_Category_ID":2},{"value":"Pelvis","Diagnosis_Code":["DIAG002","DIAG003","DIAG004"],"name":"Anatomy","FK_Diagnosis_Content_ID":6,"FK_Diagnosis_Category_ID":2}]}];
const Array2 = ['Fracture', 'Pelvis'];

const result = Array1.reduce((acc, item) => {
  item.value.forEach(i => {
    if (Array2.includes(i.value)) {
      acc.push(i.FK_Diagnosis_Content_ID);
    }
  })

  return acc;
}, []);

console.log(result);
```

BTW, the `FK_Diagnosis_Content_ID` of Fracture is `3` as opposed to what you mentioned in the question.

Comment: Wouldn't `.find` be a more appropriate method to use than `forEach` in this situation?

Comment: @CertainPerformance -- Was not sure about the uniqueness of the items. If the items are unique, `find` is the right thing to do. Otherwise, using `forEach` is correct.